# Color gradient for textcolor

Tags: android, gradient, textcolor

I have a textview. I want to change color of text by gradient but it's not work

```
 <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="#eabd00"
            android:centerColor="#fef1b2"
            android:endColor="#f9e273"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin)
Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 20,
            new int[]{R.color.colorAccent,R.color.colorPrimary},
            new float[]{0, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);
textView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

or this

```
TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
int[] color = {Color.DKGRAY,Color.CYAN};
float[] position = {0, 1};
TileMode tile_mode = TileMode.MIRROR; // or TileMode.REPEAT;
LinearGradient lin_grad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 50,color,position, tile_mode);
Shader shader_gradient = lin_grad;
txt1.getPaint().setShader(shader_gradient);
```